# Automating creation of class instances in python for an undetermined amount of instances

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I am creating a turn-based game, where the player can create units at any time during his/her turn.
A shortened version of the Unit class is:

```
class Unit(object):
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, color = 'red'):
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.color = color
```

And I was wondering if there was a way to automate creation of instances of this class, without
hardcoding something like:

```
unit1 = Unit(1, 1)
unit2 = Unit(1, 2)
...
unitn = Unit(1, 2)
```

So that I could just make a function such as create_unit(xpos, ypos, color = 'red')
and I wouldn't have to worry about hardcoding every unit spot avaliable

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: That `create_unit` function would do exactly the same thing the `Unit` constructor already does, so what would be the point?

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm pretty sure what you really want here is not `n` separate variables, but one variable with a list of `n` objects—e.g., `units = [Unit(1, 2) for _ in range(n)]`. See [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) and [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see the pattern: *unit1, unit2, ... , unitN*, you should probably be using a list to store them. If you want to create a new unit, just append a new unit to the list. Try this example:

```
units = []

# Your Unit constructor handles the creation of a new unit:
# No need to create a special function for that.
units.append(Unit(1,1))
units.append(Unit(1,2))

# etc...

print(units)
```